# Finding the number of objects in permutation

Tags: permutations

What is n in this permutation,
P(n, 3) = 60?

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail? For example, what is the definition of $P(n,3)$?

Comment: That's all there is in our 3rd grading exam i'm so sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy $\frac{n!}{(n-3)!}=60$ so $(n)(n-1)(n-2)=60$ we need to find three consecutive numbers whose product is $60$ so it can be easily seen that $5.4.3$ satisfy it thus $n=5$ .to cross check see $P(5,3)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Your welcome!!..

Comment: But how about r is missing? What's the process? I really have a hard time with statistics hehehe

Comment: $r=3$ so it isnt missing